# Certain file types not showing in Ranger preview

Tags: linux, csv, ranger, file-types

I have a bunch of csv files that are all just plain text csv files.

```
$ file ./*
file1.csv: ASCII text, with very long lines
file2.csv: CSV Text
```

I even generated file2.csv from file1.csv using `cut`. However, the files seem to be of different types.

When previewing them on ranger, file1.csv previews as expected. But when I go to preview file2.csv, it just says

```
---------------File Type Classification----------------------------
CSV Text
```

How do I fix this?

I have Ranger v1.9.3 and default config files (scope.sh, rc.conf, rifle.conf). This happens even when I run ranger as `ranger -c`

Sidenote: Any idea why `file2.csv` shows up as "CSV Text" rather than an ASCII text file even when I generated it from an ASCII text file using simple bash commands like `sed` and `cut`

Comment: Have you considered examining the first say 50 bytes of each file? Because that's what `file` typically operates on (there's somewhat more to it, as Marcus points out in his answer)...

Answer (score 0):

The "type" is just something that the `file` utility guesses based on the heuristics it's been given.

There's nothing to fix here, honestly: your comma-separated values are comma-separated values, whether or not `file` recognizes that.

The "very long lines" might indicate you're not using the right line break characters consistently in the file (e.g., some MSDOS line breaks, some UNIX line breaks). But that's a problem with how you produced the data, not something you can fix without looking at it in detail.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can get Ranger to preview both "types" ?

Comment: I'd really check the line endings!